# How to set lr_mult for convolutional layer in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, pytorch

In caffe, it has the option to set the learning multiple for convolution as follows

```
layer {
  name: "conv1a"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1a"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    kernel_size: 3
    pad: 1
    stride: 1    
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
```

In pytorch, how to set the lr_mult for convolutional layer only with SGD? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent in PyTorch. Learning rate is not considered a part of the model, but of the optimization scheme. [There is a help page](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/optim.html#per-parameter-options) on setting different learning rates per parameter, so you can do it this way. If you want to have all your parameters to have learning rate of `1.`, except for `conv1a` which is supposed to have `0.5`, you can do it like this:

```
fast_parameters = []
slow_parameters = []
for name, parameter in model.named_parameters():
    if 'conv1a' in name:
        slow_parameters.append(parameter)
     else:
        fast_parameters.append(parameter)

optimizer = optim.SGD([
    {'params': slow_parameters, 'lr': 0.5},
    {'params': fast_parameters}
], lr=1.)
```

where I make use of the [`named_parameters()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.named_parameters) method.